# sublime plugin: find and select text

Tags: python, plugins, sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublimetext3

I got plugin for `sublime text 3` that let me move cursor to line by its number:

```
import sublime, sublime_plugin

class prompt_goto_lineCommand(sublime_plugin.WindowCommand):

    def run(self):
        self.window.show_input_panel("Goto Line:", "", self.on_done, None, None)
        pass

    def on_done(self, text):
        try:
            line = int(text)
            if self.window.active_view():
                self.window.active_view().run_command("goto_line", {"line": line} )
        except ValueError:
            pass

class go_to_lineCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):

    def run(self, edit, line):
        # Convert from 1 based to a 0 based line number
        line = int(line) - 1

        # Negative line numbers count from the end of the buffer
        if line < 0:
            lines, _ = self.view.rowcol(self.view.size())
            line = lines + line + 1

        pt = self.view.text_point(line, 0)

        self.view.sel().clear()
        self.view.sel().add(sublime.Region(pt))

        self.view.show(pt)
```

I want to improve it to let me move cursor to first line containing the specified string. It is like a search on file: 
For example  if pass to it string `"class go_to_lineCommand"` plugin must move cursor to line 17 :

[image: select line by text]

and possibly select string `class go_to_lineCommand`.

The problem is reduced to finding `regionWithGivenString`, and then I can select it:

```
self.view.sel().add(regionWithGivenString)
```

But don't know method to get `regionWithGivenString`.

I tried to

1. find on google: [sublime plugin find and select text](https://www.google.ru/search?q=sublime+plugin+find+and+select+text+like+vim&oq=sublime+plugin+find+and+select+text+like+vim&aqs=chrome..69i57.2697j0j7&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8#es_sm=122&espv=210&newwindow=1&q=sublime+plugin+find+and+select+text)
2. check [api](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/api_reference.html)

But still no result.

Comment: why the hell you need plugin for that? Why you cannot just use  Ctrl+G/Ctrl+F?

Comment: it is just part of big plugin for fast navigating: imagine I got code in `iced coffee script`: `a = (require './c/d/e/file.js').doMethod()`. I move cursor on this line, press short key and this sublime plugin opens file `file.js` and select `doMethod` method for me.

Comment: I know you have a solution for this already, but just thought I would also point you in the right direction in terms of the docs. Take a look at `view#find` and `view#find_all`. They return a region and an array of regions respectively. Of course, the end result will be the same as the plugin provided by lhuang.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure about the typical way. However, you can achieve this in following way:

1. Get the content of current doc.
2. Search target string to find out its start and end position. Now you have the start and end point.
3. Add the `Region(start, end)` to selections.

Example:

```
def run(self, edit, target):
    if not target or target == "":
        return

    content = self.view.substr(sublime.Region(0, self.view.size()))
    begin = content.find(target)
    if begin == -1:
        return
    end = begin + len(target)
    target_region = sublime.Region(begin, end)
    self.view.sel().clear()
    self.view.sel().add(target_region)
```

Answer (score 2):

there you have it in the API, use the view.find(regex,pos) method.

```
s = self.view.find("go_to_lineCommand", 0)
self.view.sel().add(s)
```

http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/api_reference.html

Answer (score 1):

A possible improvement to the longhua's answer - adding moving cursor to the target line.

```
class FindcustomCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    def _select(self):
        self.view.sel().clear()
        self.view.sel().add(self._target_region)

    def run(self, edit):
        TARGET = 'http://nabiraem'

        # if not target or target == "":
        #   return

        content = self.view.substr(sublime.Region(0, self.view.size()))
        begin = content.find(TARGET)
        if begin == -1:
            return
        end = begin + len(TARGET)
        self._target_region = sublime.Region(begin, end)    
        self._select()
        self.view.show(self._target_region) # scroll to selection
```