# automatic update date in sublime by save?

Tags: sublimetext, sublimetext3

is there a way that sublime text automatically updates the date in a comment block on a file when I edit and save it?

like:

```
/**
 * @author yada yada
 * @date 2015-01-08
 */
```

to:

```
/**
 * @author yada yada
 * @date 2015-01-19
 */
```

Answer (score 5):

ok, got it.
it's a mix of

- [Can i add date time for sublime snippet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11879481/can-i-add-date-time-for-sublime-snippet)
- [sublime plugin: find and select text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19721965/sublime-plugin-find-and-select-text)
- [Is it possible to chain key binding commands in sublime text 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9646552/is-it-possible-to-chain-key-binding-commands-in-sublime-text-2)

Preferences > Key Bindings- User

```
[
    {"keys": ["ctrl+s"], "command": "date_and_save" }
]
```

add_date.py

```
'''
Autodate header
@date <>
'''
from datetime import datetime
import sublime, sublime_plugin

class AddDateCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    def run(self, args):
        content = self.view.substr(sublime.Region(0, self.view.size()))
        begin = content.find('@date <',0,100)
        if begin == -1:
            return
        end = content.find("\n", begin)
        target_region = sublime.Region(begin, end)
        self.view.sel().clear()
        self.view.sel().add(target_region)

        self.view.run_command(
        "insert_snippet",
        { "contents": "@date <%s>" % datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") } )

class DateAndSaveCommand(sublime_plugin.WindowCommand):
    def run(self):
        self.window.run_command("add_date")
        self.window.run_command("save")
```

\o/

Comment: you are using ctrl+s key binding, in this case files will not save.

Comment: Limiting the replacement of  `date` occurrence to a range of N first characters makes it safer. You probably don't want an other occurrence of `date` to be replaced in the code. An even better approach would be to indicate how much lines to scan. You might also want the hour of the file's revision. The C-s keybinding works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Awesome stuff! Small addition to the above solution:

Instead of

```
end = begin + 19
```

This line will make it more dynamical, because it will get rid of everything until the end of the line.

```
end = content.find("\n", begin)
```

Helps with versioning up, for example, where the line-length can vary.

Comment: This would be better as a comment -- since it doesn't directly answer the question.

Comment: I agree - I wanted to do that, but since I'm a new user it didn't let me comment :( Sorry about that.